# ClickOnce Prerequisites not being published to webserver

Tags: clickonce

I have generated a Bootstrapper Manifest using the Bootstrapper Manifest Generator tool.  The Package has been successfully installed in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\`

The package seems to have been successfully created as it shows up in the list of available prerequisites from the project's publish properties page.  After checking the package and 
publishing the application, I do not see the prerequisite folder anywhere under the main application directory on my webserver.  Any ideas?

Comment: "main application directory" - are you referring to Application Files here?

Comment: No.

C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\MyApplication.

Comment: The Setup.msi and accompanying cab files are huge:  The Setup file is 10MB and CAB file is 315MB.  Does ClickOnce have a problem copying such large files?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have "Create setup program to install prerequisite components" checked, along with the correct option for "Specify the install location for prerequisits":

[image]

Comment: "Create setup program to install prerequisite components" is checked and I had "Download prerequisites from the component vendor's web site" checked.  Changing to download from same location generates error 

The install location for prerequisites has not been set to 'component vendor's web site' and the file 'DotNetFX35SP1\dotNetFX20\aspnet.msp' in item '.NET Framework 3.5 SP1' can not be located on disk. See Help for more information. c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.Common.targets 

First package is getting copied just fine.

Comment: Check here: http://geekrick.blogspot.com/2008/08/frustrating-net-framework-sp1-issue.html

Answer (score 0):

Solved problem:

Manually editing product.xml bychanging CopyAllPackageFiles to true i.e

CopyAllPackageFiles="true

fixed this problem.  setup.msi and associated cab files were published successfully to the server.  I have not found a way to set this from the BMG tool.